Does morality exist independently of humans or is it a social construct?
Plato believed that objective moral truths existed separate from human experience, Kant argued that morality is grounded in universal principles (such as his categorical imperative. Nietzsche claims that morals are used for power and control rather than reflecting any inherent truths. I've seen some contentious debates on issues such as moral realism vs anti-realism but I wanted to see the strongest arguments for each side of the debate.
Is there a definitive answer to whether morality exists independently of human experience, or is it something that we’ve constructed over time based on societal needs?

Those aren't exhaustive possibilities.

This is not a place to see "strongest arguments". There are encyclopedias presenting arguments, for example SEP, Arguing For and Against Moral Anti-realism, it is up to you to decide which are the "strongest". Whether God or free will exist, whether consciousness is physical or not, or whether mathematics is invented or discovered, we cannot resolve here either. This Q&A site is not meant for solving perennial problems.

morality is sophistry and hand waving, social construct as you call it

Morals are a set of rules, specific to a human group (meaning that not all groups share the same rules) that essentially allow social (internal) peace, social cohesion, cooperation, etc. What are the goals of having cohesion, peace, cooperation, etc.? The survival of the group (see Social Darwinism: Herbert Spencer et.al.).
So, the objective of morals is the survival of the group.
Let's see some perspectives about it.
War
Now, are those rules universal? If they were universal, we all just need to follow them to maximize the survival probabilities of our societies.
But such is an illusion. This is the logical development of such fact:

Different societies will ALWAYS have different abilities, knowledge, resources, etc.
So, different societies will ALWAYS have different interests.
So, different societies will ALWAYS have conflicts of interests.
Conflicts of interests between societies imply, in part, solving them by means of dialog; and in part, by means of war.
A set of universal moral principles is ALWAYS inconsistent with the necessity of war.

Natural Selection
From a different perspective, which is a trivial conclusion of Social Darwinism, each society develops their own social rules, and each group tries surviving using them. Who decides which society survives? Nature, by means of natural selection.
Simple Observation
The notion of social group is not necessarily associated with a nation or a urban area. Villages, sports teams, associations, religious groups or families are also social groups. The rules of survival also apply to them.
You can simply observe that the moral rules of your group of friends are different from the rules of a drug traffic gang. Which has more probabilities to survive? It depends. Many are losing the battle, and drug trafficking groups rule thousands of cities.
Scale
As observed, morals cannot be universal. Your morals will always differ with mine, not just because we think different, but because WE ARE DIFFERENT: each one has different potentials, abilities, resources, knowledge, history, etc. So, each one will follow different rules. For example, if you're an agricultor, you might be vegetarian and consider immoral to kill animals. Me, on the contrary, I like eating meat and think that killing animals is completely consistent with morals. And we both can leave together and in peace (exactly what happens right now with most human beings: different morals could increase the survival probabilities of all humanity).
This perspective highlights the benefits of synergy: we are different, and such difference makes our joint potential more than the addition of our isolated potentials.

So the metamorality is to get along. If people with differences coexist, then 1) they don't risk their lives and waste resources fighting, and 2) the differences are often helpful. So then it becomes a simpler question: what can't groups tolerate? Maybe we can still label that 'morality', but as you say, it becomes more of a pragmatic and experiential question rather than some theoretical one.

There is no "metamorality" since it would imply a set of universal moral rules, the fact that is being challenged. For the comment, absolutely not. Differences allow either collaboration (e.g. working together for resources) or competition (e.g. killing for resources), both of which are critical matters in natural selection.

Probably you are correct. Often cooperation gives better results. If that is true in general, it's like a law of nature. Maybe that's better than morality? I'm thinking of the Game Theory results. Algorithmic participants can't be said to exercise morality, yet they still have benefit or loss based on choices made. If you kill the person who could save you in the future, there is no way to call that useful.
